# Christian Science Fiction novel. Air force pilot meets alien and flies his F-111 to the moon

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the name and author of a book written in the 80's or 90's about an Air Force pilot that meets up with a woman who is an alien.

He flies his F-111 fighter to The Moon to meet up with her and the mother-ship.

The cover of the book shows the F-111 sitting on the moon.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: What made it _Christian_ SF?

Comment: +1 the comment above - clarifying "Christian Science" fiction novel, or "Christian" science fiction novel

Comment: @NKCampbell - Well it's hardly likely to be the former on a sci-fi website